# Is there a way to apply [TestMethod] to all methods withing a class

Tags: c#, mstest

I am getting really hacked off with having to type [TestMethod] at the top of each method in my class. At present I have over 600 tests in my project. Is there a way that I can add this attribute through and IL weaver like PostSharp or fody? or can I add one class attribute that will do the same?

cheers

Comment: you wrote 600 methods, each of which is more than one line, what is the problem of putting one more line in head? :)

Comment: The TestMethod attribute allows you to intermix supporting methods with tests. It also exposes ways for you to ignore specific tests within your suite. I'm not sure I see why you would want to do this...

Comment: I'd highly recommend also making use of `[TestCategory]`. It can be applied multiple times to a method, and allows you to set categories for your tests. Particularly useful so you can focus down in TestManager to only run the tests affecting your feature. In which case you need to decorate them anyway so you might as well do `TestMethod` at the same time.

Comment: the system im writing is a pure TDD/BDD driven system ive still got a few hundred more tests to write as the system evolves. Using good coding practices all my supporting method are stored else where and injected in where required. Most of the methods are only 1 or two lines, but the attribute is adding unecessary complexity. [TestCategory] is another pointless MS invention that provides no benefit - if you structure the code correctly there is not need for categories. They are only needed if your creating huge GOD classes, a really bad practice

Comment: @Justdeserves That's simply not true. You can use `TestCategory` in conjunction with your CI solution to ensure that certain tests are excluded from running during CI. This can be very useful if, for example, you have a few tests that perform heavy data processing and take a little bit too long to run. You can pare down your CI builds to just the absolutely critical tests using test categories, then have a nightly/scheduled build that runs *all* the tests, including the long-running ones.

Comment: @Daniel - that's one way, but as test shoudl be small and isolated I find it much simpler to push the heavy type of tests you describe into their own test DLL and vary the build definsition appropriately. This removes cognative load from developers of having to worry about what category of test they are writing - it just has to be in the right place

Answer (score 2):

The only idea that comes in mind to me is to write your own method with attribute [ClassInitialize] which will run before tests execution. Method implementation: using reflection go through all methods in specific class and add attribute at runtime. There is no out of the box solution to your problem.

Comment: although this was a good suggestion it will not achieve what is desired under my current method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use find and replace and replace the public void with [TestMethod] public void :)